# In Azure DevOps how to make pull request in a incremental manner

Tags: azure-devops, increment, pull-request

​Our team recently started to use Azure DevOps. So we are learning all the time. So far, we haven't found a way incremental pull request. We have to abandon a pull request and make a new pull request. This is really bad way of doing pull request. Because we lose all comments and code reviewer has to review all over again. As you know there is always some review comments minor or major. So If we abandoned and make fresh pull request. It is a terrible way. How can we do it in an incremental way as it is done in the Gerrit?

Comment: What do you mean by incremental and what would you like to obtain? I'm not familiar with how it exactly works in Gerrit.

Comment: I meant by incremental is that developer Mike makes first pull request and developer Bob reviews it. Mike fixed it and makes a second pull request. In the second pull request, all comment from first pull request and fix exist in the second pull request.  This way pull requst 1, 2, 3, 4 goes on.  If we abandon a pull requst all comment disappeared. Then all starts from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want is done by simply committing changes to the source branch in the pull request. When you create a pull request in Azure Devops from branch A to B, whenever new code is committed to either A or B you will see these changes in the same PR. There is no need to abandon it or recreate.

Instead, push changes per code review comments, apply new comments on the 2nd round of code review and so on. This process can be done incrementally.

**Update**: notification settings appeared to be the root cause. It can be changed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-requests?view=azure-devops#receiving-notification-of-pull-request-updates).

Comment: Yes, we tried this. But this way reviewer doesn't get any email notification for any update on the active pull request unless it is abandoned and recreate new pull request.

Comment: So this is is a matter of notification settings. You can read how to adjust them [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-requests?view=azure-devops#receiving-notification-of-pull-request-updates).

Comment: **pbalaga** pointed to the right direction to set the notification( i think it should be `pull request changes`.). How did it go?